# Why isn't "k" incremented in the statement "m = ++i && ++j || ++k" when "++i&&++j" evaluates to true?

Tags: c, expression, logical-operators

Aren't the individual expressions in a composite logical **AND/OR**  expression supposed to be evaluated first before the logical operators are applied to their result?Why is `++k` untouched in the condition `m = ++i && ++j || ++k` for the following program :

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
      int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m;
    m = ++i && ++j || ++k;
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k, m);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output :**  -2,3,0,1

But I expect the output `-2,3,1,1`

Comment: Because **short circuiting** is guaranteed by the standard. Since `++i && ++j` evaluates to `true`, irrespective of evaluation of `||` the final outcome will be evaluated to `true` and hence the final `||` is simply not evaluated. This is known as short circuiting. C & C++ standard guarantees this behavior for `||` and `&&` operators.

Comment: I did answer, but I can't understand why people first ask on StackOverflow before diving into their C programming language book.

Comment: "Aren't the individual expressions in a composite logical AND/OR expression supposed to be evaluated first " -- No, of course they aren't, as even the most basic reading on C would tell you.

Comment: @ruppell's Yes of course you will get your output just by replacing the logical OR operator to bitwise OR operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should avoid coding such unreadable code. It is actually parsed as

```
m = (++i && ++j) || ++k;
```

So once `j >= 0` the `++j` condition is always true, so `++k` is not evaluated since `&&` is a short-cutting *and then* but `||` is a short-cutting *or else* (so they may not evaluate their right operand).

So `&&` is evaluated as follow: the left operand is evaluated, if it is false it is returned, and then only when it is true (i.e. not equal to `0`) the right operand is evaluated and returned as the evaluated result of the `&&`. Likewise `||` is evaluated as follow: the left operand is evaluated. If it is true (non-zero) it becomes the result of the `||`; or else the right operand is evaluated and is the result of the `||` expression.

In particular, when coding `if (x > 0 && 20/x < 5)` the division is never attempted for `x==0` .

Read also the wikipedia [operators in C & C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) & [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) & [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) pages; and please take several hours to read a good C programming book.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "and then" and "or else" part.

Comment: Thanks.But I guess there is a typo in the line `"then only when it is true (i.e. not equal to 0) the right operator"`.It is supposed to be `right operand`

Comment: Thanks. Typo corrected

Answer (score 1):

Logical operators have short circuit evaluation, i.e. as soon as a value is determined for the expression, the rest of the expression is not evaluated.

e.g.  `m = ++i && ++j || ++k;`
in this ++i -> true, ++j -> true (non zero value)
hence `m = true && true || ++k;`

now true && true is true
so

```
m = true || ++k
```

As in OR operator if 1 side is true, the other is not evaluated so result is true.

Hence k is not incremented.

Answer (score 0):

That is a shortcut for logical operators, in your case operator `||`. When the first operand is `true`, it's impossible for the second operand to have any impact on the result. It will always be true, not matter what the second operand may yield. So the second operand is not evaluated.

The same goes for the logical `&&` operator, if the first operand is found to be `false`. The second operand will not matter, the result will always be `false` and the second operand will therefor not be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` and `||` are logical operators, and you are using them out of context which is odd (ok for C/C++ but you'd have type errors in Java or C#).

You've have just discovered short circuiting operators - you don't need to evaluate the whole expression if you "know" it's true. i.e. i and j are non zero so you don't need to do anything with k since you know the expression is true.

Answer (score 0):

m = ++i && ++j || ++k;

Above line of code executes ++i and ++j first and doesn't execute ++k since it's written after || (OR)

Logical Circuit Operators don't execute when previously statement is true already in case of || and false in case of &&

Hence k is untouched