# Why isn't “k” incremented in the statement “m = ++i || ++j && ++k”?

Tags: c++, c, expression, logical-operators

1st part:

```
i=j=k=1;
m = ++i && ++j || ++k;
printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k, m);
```

output: 2, 2, 1, 1

1st part easily understood ,Here `++i && ++j` execute first, which is true (and increment value of i and j) so there  is no need to check next part of OR operation(no need increment value of k) .

2nd part:

```
i=j=k=1;
m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k, m);
```

output: 2, 1, 1, 1

2nd part confusing to understand ,Here `++i || ++j` execute first, in which `++i` is true (and increment value of `i`, since OR opreation so no need to increment value of `j` ). Next execute AND operation here should be increment value of `k=2`(**but still value of k print 1**).

Dear altruist, please explain me what happen in 2nd part.

Comment: `true || <whatever> == true` for any value of `whatever`. If that's the case, why bother with `whatever`?

Comment: What does your favorite C book say? Or any operator overview for C? Did you even try to answer this yourself first?

Comment: Not sure ++j && ++k executes first because of operator precedence.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271779/why-isnt-k-incremented-in-the-statement-m-i-j-k-when-i

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||` in C/C++, rendering your code as:

```
m = ++i || (++j && ++k);
```

As `++i` is already true, the second part is not executed ([short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)).

See http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence for operator precedences.

Answer (score -3):

I think your use of `i, j, k, and m` might be making it more difficult for you to see what is happening.

```
int i, j, k;

i=j=1;
k = ++i && ++j;
printf("%d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k); // 2, 2, 1

i=j=1;
k = ++i || ++j;
printf("%d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k); // 2, 1, 1
```

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation to learn more about the concept behind what you are seeing and http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence if you'd like more info on operator precedence.